# ListBox vertical scroll bar not working in menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a menu where I have to display several item types. Here is sample of the code of what I have for now:

```
   <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,40,0,0" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <MenuItem Header="(None)" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="False">
                        <MenuItem Header="Aggregation">
                            <MenuItem Header="Sum"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Average"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <Separator/>
                        <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                            <MenuItem Header="Test0" IsCheckable="True"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Test1" IsCheckable="True"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Test2" IsCheckable="True"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Test3" IsCheckable="True"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Test4" IsCheckable="True"/>
                        </ListBox>
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Test5" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
```

If you notice, there is a ListBox there. I set the vertical scroll viewer to visible and it never activates no matter how many items I add. If you are wondering, yes, I tried with ListBoxItem instead of MenuItems and did not make a difference. Is there a different way to do this? How do I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: Using a ListBox in a menu is probably not what you want. Consider rethinking/redesigning your menu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `MaxHeight` otherwise the ListBox will just stretch as much as it needs to display all of its elements.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="250" />
```

That said, like AkselK commented, this does not look like good design.
You could simply keep on creating submenus.